# Customize the diary template insert from org calendar

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Striking `i j` on calender's date will insert a date in diary.org

[image]

The template inserted is

```
** 2019-09 September
*** 2019-09-01 Sunday
```

How could change it to

```
** 2019-09 September
*** 2019-09-01 Sunday
**** Personal_Notes
**** Personal_Tasks
**** Project_Notes
**** Project_Tasks
```

Comment: You can add a post-advice to `org-agenda-diary-entry-in-org-file` to add the extra stuff, but that has the potential of affecting other situations where you *don't* want the extra stuff. If I were you, I'd just define some sort of abbrev for the extra stuff and insert it manually (there are many abbrev systems available, from [basic abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html) to [dynamic abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html#Dynamic-Abbrevs) ...

Comment: ... to [hippie expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Hippie-Expand.html#Hippie-Expand) to [yasnippets](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) and probably many more. I'd start with basic abbrevs.

Comment: ty, I created a yasnippet. @NickD